# "Bad request" error (HTTP) while posting to PHP server using Arduino and ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, esp8266, http

I'm doing an IoT project where the temperature and humidity values from a DHT11 sensor is sent to a PHP server using HTTP post. When I run the Arduino, the Serial Monitor says "Bad request". The sensor values are not appearing on the webpage. Please, help me figure out the problem. I am using an Arduino Uno with and an ESP-01.

```c++
// Code to use SoftwareSerial
//The final sketch
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include <dht.h>

#define dht_dpin 8

String data;
String ssid = "TRAK family";

String password = "rukman12345";

SoftwareSerial espSerial(6, 7); // RX, TX

dht DHT;

float t;
float h;

String server = "svce-ece-b.000webhostapp.com";

String uri = "esp.php";

boolean DEBUG = true;

void showResponse(int waitTime)
{
    long t = millis();
    char c;
    while (t + waitTime > millis()) {
        if (espSerial.available()) {
            c = espSerial.read();
            if (DEBUG)
                Serial.print(c);
        }
    }
}

void setup()
{
    DEBUG = true;

    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(500);

    espSerial.begin(115200);

    espSerial.println("AT+RST");
    showResponse(1000);

    // espSerial.println("CIOBAUD=9600");
    // showResponse(1000);

    espSerial.println("AT+CWMODE=1");
    showResponse(1000);

    espSerial.println("AT+CWJAP=\"" + ssid + "\",\"" + password + "\"");
    showResponse(5000);

    if (DEBUG)
        Serial.println("Setup completed");
}

void httppost()
{
    espSerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"" + server + "\",80");

    if (espSerial.find("OK")) {
        Serial.println("TCP connection ready");
    }
    delay(1000);

    String postRequest =
        "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.0\r\n" +
        "Host: " + server + "\r\n" +
        "Accept: *" + "/" + "*\r\n" +
        "Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" +
        "\r\n" + data;

    String sendCmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    espSerial.print(sendCmd);
    espSerial.println(postRequest.length());

    delay(500);

    if (espSerial.find(">")) {
        Serial.println("Sending..");
        espSerial.print(postRequest);

        if (espSerial.find("SEND OK")) {
            Serial.println("Packet sent");
            while (espSerial.available()) {
                String tmpResp = espSerial.readString();
                Serial.println(tmpResp);
            }

            // close the connection
            espSerial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
        }
    }
}

void loop()
{
    // Read sensor values
    DHT.read11(dht_dpin);
    float t = DHT.temperature;
    float h = DHT.humidity;
    if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
        if (DEBUG)
            Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
    }
    else {
        if (DEBUG)
            Serial.println("Temp=" + String(t) + " *C");
        if (DEBUG)
            Serial.println("Humidity=" + String(h) + " %");

        data = "temperature=" + String(t) + "&humidity=" + String(h);

        httppost();
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

This is my PHP code:

```php
<?php
    global $Temp;
    global $Humidity;
    if(isset($_POST['temperature'])){
        $Temp=$_POST["temperature"];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['humidity'])){
        $Humidity=$_POST["humidity"];
    }

    $Write="<p>Temperature : " .$Temp . " Celcius </p>" . "<p>Humidity : " .       $Humidity . " % </p>";
    file_put_contents('sensor.html',$Write);
?>
```

Comment: `the serial monitor says bad request`   ... the code that you posted does not contain the text `bad request` ... the message does not come from the code that you posted

Comment: @jsotola That's probably the response from the server.

Comment: `uri` should start with /.

Comment: @gre_gor thanks brother. it resolved my issure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI path in the HTTP request must start with a `/`.

It should be:

```cpp
String uri = "/esp.php";
```